# Text mining with tm.plugin.webmining package using GoogleFinanceSource function

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I am studying text mining on the online book http://tidytextmining.com/.
In the fifth chapter:
http://tidytextmining.com/dtm.html#financial

the following code:

```
library(tm.plugin.webmining)
library(purrr)

company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", "Facebook",
             "Twitter", "IBM", "Yahoo", "Netflix")
symbol <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "TWTR", "IBM", "YHOO", "NFLX")

download_articles <- function(symbol) {
    WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))
}
stock_articles <- data_frame(company = company,
                             symbol = symbol) %>%
    mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))
```

gives me the error:

```
StartTag: invalid element name
Extra content at the end of the document
Error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name
2: Extra content at the end of the document
```

Any hints? 
Someone suggested to remove company and symbol related to "Twitter", but it still doesn't work and returns the same error.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the package `tm.plugin.webmining` is out of date.

Only the `YahooFinanceSource` and `YahooNewsSource` are alive at the time of this reply.

---

Here is a quick reference and test.

From the [Vignette page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm.plugin.webmining/vignettes/ShortIntro.pdf) written by the author, there should be 8 possible source sites:

1. GoogleBlogSearchSource
2. GoogleFinaceSource
3. GoogleNewsSource
4. NYTimesSource
5. ReutersNewsSource
6. YahooFinanceSource
7. YahooInplaySource
8. YahooNewsSource

But according to the [Github page](https://github.com/mannau/tm.plugin.webmining), the first one "GoogleBlogSearchSource" has already been proven to be discontinued. For the 7 sources remained, I did a simple test to see if they work:

```
library(tm)
library(tm.plugin.webmining)

googlefinance <- WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource("A"))
googlenews <- WebCorpus(GoogleNewsSource("A"))
nytimes <- WebCorpus(NYTimesSource("A", appid = nytimes_appid))
reutersnews <- WebCorpus(ReutersNewsSource("A"))
yahoofinance <- WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource("A"))
yahooinplay <- WebCorpus(YahooInplaySource())
yahoonews <- WebCorpus(YahooNewsSource("M"))
```

The result shows that all the yahoo's sourses are technically still running, but the `YahooInplaySource` returns 0 documents no matter what parameter I chose.

```
> googlefinance <- WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource("NASDAQ:MSFT"))
StartTag: invalid element name
Extra content at the end of the document
Error in inherits(x, "WebSource") : 1: StartTag: invalid element name
2: Extra content at the end of the document
> googlefinance <- WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource("A"))
StartTag: invalid element name
Extra content at the end of the document
Error in inherits(x, "WebSource") : 1: StartTag: invalid element name
2: Extra content at the end of the document
> googlenews <- WebCorpus(GoogleNewsSource("A"))
Unknown IO errorfailed to load external entity "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q=A&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss"
Error in inherits(x, "WebSource") : 
  1: Unknown IO error2: failed to load external entity "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q=A&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss"
> nytimes <- WebCorpus(NYTimesSource("A", appid = nytimes_appid))
Error in inherits(x, "WebSource") : object 'nytimes_appid' not found
> reutersnews <- WebCorpus(ReutersNewsSource("A"))
Entity 'ldquo' not defined
Entity 'rdquo' not defined
Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 60 and body
Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 59 and html
Premature end of data in tag html line 1
Error in inherits(x, "WebSource") : 1: Entity 'ldquo' not defined
2: Entity 'rdquo' not defined
3: Opening and ending tag mismatch: div line 60 and body
4: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 59 and html
5: Premature end of data in tag html line 1
> yahoofinance <- WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource("A"))
> yahoofinance
<<WebCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 3, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 16
> yahooinplay <- WebCorpus(YahooInplaySource())
> yahooinplay
<<WebCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 3, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 0
> yahoonews <- WebCorpus(YahooNewsSource("A"))
> yahoonews
<<WebCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 3, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 0
> yahoonews <- WebCorpus(YahooNewsSource("M"))
> yahoonews
<<WebCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 3, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 10
```

Also it worth to be mentioned that even though `YahooFinanceSourse` is working, it won't return the similar content as `GoogleFinanceSource` was supposed to do. If you want to play with the examples in , I think you may use `YahooNewsSource` with a customized list of queries.

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue, however, have narrowed it down slightly. This snippet of the code results in the same error.

```
GoogleFinanceSource("NASDAQ:MSFT")
```

> ```
> StartTag: invalid element name
> Extra content at the end of the document
> Error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name
> 2: Extra content at the end of the document
> ```

I also saw where others have suggested removing Twitter. I get the point it would have failed as Twitter is not on NASDAQ. I tried the suggested "NYSE:TWTR" and got the same result, however.

I attempted to use GoogleNewsSource to see if I would get the same issue and got a different error which this article on github suggests is being caused by the parser. I wonder if these two issues could be related. github.com/mannau/tm.plugin.webmining/issues/14.

```
GoogleNewsSource("Microsoft")
```

> ```
> Unknown IO error failed to load external entity "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q=Microsoft&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss"
> Error: 1: Unknown IO error2: failed to load external entity "http://news.google.com/news?hl=en&q=Microsoft&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss"
> ```

That all being said, I have found a work around using a modified ticker list and  YahooFinanceSource as follows:

```
company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google")
symbol <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG")

download_articles <- function(symbol) {
    WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource(symbol))
}

stock_articles <- data_frame(company = company,
                         symbol = symbol) %>%
mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))
```

Comment: I appreciate your attempt, but you don't answer my question as I wish. In particular, I would like to understand whether is possible to use `GoogleFinanceSource` or not and why.

Answer (score -1):

In the line of code below, try to change the default ie = "utf-8" to ie = "ansi". Try and apply it to your script, it should work.

```
WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource("NASDAQ:MSFT", params = list(hl = "en", q = "NASDAQ:MSFT", ie = "ansi", start = 0, num = 20, output = "rss")))
```