# Problems text mining using the ‘rJava’ and ‘tm.plugin.webmining’ packages

Tags: r, finance, tm, web-mining

I apologize if my formatting of this topic isn’t correct this is my first time posting in the community and I will try and do my best.I have been working on this problem for awhile but have been struggling to address it. I am currently following the book “Text Mining with R: A Tidy Data Approach” and am on the part that uses the ‘tm.plugin.webmining’ package to do a sentiment analysis on financial articles. The initial problem is that when I attempted to load the package from the library it would report and error as such.

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tm.plugin.webmining’:
>   .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for ‘rJava’, details:
>   call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, …)
>   error: unable to load shared object ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so’:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
>   Reason: image not found

After doing some research I found out that this had to do with the way R and Java communicate on mac OS High Sierra. So to fix this I followed the followed this article. and it appeared to work. once I fixed the issue with java and r I was finally able to load the ‘tm.plugin.webmining’ package. but when I tried to run the examples from the book to load the corpus, I got the following error.

> StartTag: invalid element name
>   Extra content at the end of the document
>   Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>   Evaluation error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name
>   2: Extra content at the end of the document

I cannot seem to find information on this anywhere and do not have enough experience in this to fix this issue myself, so any insight, or ideas I could attempt to fix this problem are greatly appreciated. Below I posted the code I ran that gave me this issue. Thank you in advance.

```
`library(tm.plugin.webmining)

library(purrr)

library(dplyr)

company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google", "Amazon", 
"Facebook","IBM", "Yahoo", "Netflix") 
symbol <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB", "IBM", "YHOO", 
"NFLX")

download_articles <- function( symbol) { 
WebCorpus(GoogleFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))
}

stock_articles <- data_frame(company = company, symbol = symbol) %>% 
mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))`
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:java]?

Comment: Dylan, any problems you have already resolved (like the R-Java interaction) should be removed from the question, as they are irrelevant.

Comment: I posted the same question 10 days ago with no answer...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790148/text-mining-with-tm-plugin-webmining-package-using-googlefinancesource-function

Comment: @joeC I tagged it as java because the original problem had to do with mac and java interaction and I assumed that the continued problem had to do with the way rJava is interacting with the 'tm.plugin,webmining' package

Comment: @DylanEdmonds that's ok, the tag can be removed. Java is not the best tag since its reserve to issues directly associated to the language which is not this case.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while executing the code, and found a workout, as shown below:

```
library(tm.plugin.webmining)
library(purrr)

company <- c("Microsoft", "Apple", "Google",
             "Amazon", "Facebook", "Twitter",
             "IBM", "Yahoo", "Netflix")

symbol <- c("MSFT", "AAPL", "GOOG", "AMZN", "FB",
            "TWTR", "IBM", "YHOO", "NFLX")

download_articles <- function(symbol) {
  WebCorpus(YahooFinanceSource(paste0("NASDAQ:", symbol)))
}

stock_articles <- data_frame(company = company,
                             symbol = symbol) %>%
  mutate(corpus = map(symbol, download_articles))
```

Inside the WebCorpus function, use `YahooFinanceSource()`, instead of `GoogleFinanceSource()`.